# How do I build instances on a grid with Geo Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using geometry nodes to make a grid of icons. I have instanced the icon object over a Grid node. How can I make the instances of the icon appear as if the grid is building from the bottom left to right then row after row?
If I have to animate a material to make them appear then I was hoping to use the list of icons to alter properties like color or size as well as.

[image: Gris of icons]

Comment: I don't know geonodes, but looking at your screenshot alone, you could probably achieve it with two grids, first grid having **Vertices X**=`6`, **Vertices Y**=`#floor(frame/7), and another grid having **Vertices X**=`#frame % 7`, but you would also need to position the second grid above the first so they seem like one grid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Version 3.0 one can access the index of vertices created by the [Grid](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh_primitives/grid.html) node.

Here's the setup :

[image]

1. Instantiate a grid
2. Rotate it so the indices start filling from bottom-left to top-right
3. Delete points which index is inferior to a given input value
4. Instance your desired mesh on the points

Result:

[image]

Comment: nice one Gorgious! ;)

Comment: Any chance to update this to Blender 3? I tried myself but don't know enough yet

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic done !

Answer (score 5):

you can do this with this node setup:

[image]

Result:

[image]

for color you can use something like this (since you didn't specify your color...i took kind of random)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Video tutorial with step by step explanation:

https://youtu.be/IbuA-JinG4c

Comment: Thank you for this. I was hoping it would be a little more straightforward but I will accept your answer ;-)

Comment: I was half way through my answer, but looks like we had the same idea ^^ oh, well..!

Comment: I think I will change the accepted answer to reward additional explanation tho :D

Comment: does this mean, you will change to mine again, if i would explain it more? :D

Comment: Hey that color addition is very helpful! I think that in the spirit of StackEx I would have to award the most detailed earliest answer sorry. I probably should have waited a day to award the token. Thank you so much for helping me. I see that there is much interest here too. I have many more simple questions for Geo Nodes so there will be more opportunities for detailed answers ;-)